# A question regarding MySQL master-slave replication

Tags: mysql, replication

I want to set up a one-master-one-slave replication. But I have a question. Suppose the read-load is distributed between the master and the slave. I first write to the master and then read from the slave. At this time the information has not reached the slave. So my read will fail. But I have written it! How is such a problem solved or avoided in practice?

Answer (score 0):

For some use-cases, the (usually) small delay before the data appears on the slave isn't a problem.

For "critical" reads, you could send them to the master only.

Another solution would be to use so-called synchronous replication, though actual synchronous replication doesn't really exist. The technology used in Galera Cluster (used by MariaDB Cluster and Percona XtraDB Cluster) is *virtually* synchronous. The same is true for MySQL's InnoDB Cluster.

Answer (score 0):

semi synchronous replication can solve the issue (depends on how large transactions will hit to master, if its heavy yes even semi sync will turnout into asynchronous replication)